# Stuck in a while loop on the client side

Tags: c, unix, while-loop

I have a problem with client server programming in C.

The problem is the code is stuck in a while loop in the **Client** code.  The code is @ Client:

```
while ((n_read=((read(sockfd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer))))>0)
{   
    buffer[n_read]='\0';                            
    write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    printf("------- the value of n_read is : %d\n",n_read)  ;
}
```

So when I debug this code using strace on the client side here is the snap of system calls. I saw that  the value of n_read after reading the whole file from server is 1 ,but the server exits from reading normally after read=0 ???
How can I solve this problem

**the snap of Client code :**

```
read(3, "._guardAgainstUnicode(pad)\n# Pad"..., 1025) = 1025
write(4, ".", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "------- the value of n_read is :"..., 35------- the value of n_read is : 1
) = 35
read(3, "crypted\nwith the already specifi"..., 1025) = 1025
write(4, "c", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "------- the value of n_read is :"..., 35------- the value of n_read is : 1
) = 35
read(3, " = bytes.fromhex('').join(result"..., 1025) = 1025
write(4, " ", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "------- the value of n_read is :"..., 35------- the value of n_read is : 1
) = 35
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing `)` on your `while` declaration... but it's hard to count because there's so many.

Comment: What you describe will happen when the server does not close the TCP connection. So, verify that the server does close the connection. read() will return <= 0 when the connection gets closed, and your loop will end.

Comment: Yep, you have 6 `(` and 5 `)` for the while condition.

Comment: thnx in advanced for your advices ,but i know the read will close  on <=0,but i cant make this condtion ,coz if i do it the read will read nothing and will never enter the loop...so ???

Comment: WHY the silly strlen(), why not just use the value obtained from `read()` : `write(fd, buffer, n_read);`

Comment: Also, it looks like you might have an off-by-one error.  You're reading sizeof(buffer) and writing a `NULL` after the end (if n_read == sizeof(buffer))

Comment: Thanks all but i've tried all your suggested solutions but nothing work its still stuck on loop or the reading will be contains error????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is writing outside of the buffer.

If the the number of bytes read fills the buffer, `n_read` will equal  `sizeof(buffer)`.  Then `buffer[n_read]='\0'` will write *past* the end of `buffer`.

```
while ((n_read=((read(sockfd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer))))>0) 
{   
    buffer[n_read]='\0';
```

instead use `n_read` to determine the `write()` length.

```
ssize_t n_read;
char buffer[1024];
while ((n_read = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0) {    
  // buffer[n_read]='\0';                            
  // write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
  write(fd, buffer, n_read);
  printf("------- the value of n_read is : %zu\n", (size_t) n_read)  ;
}
```

---

[Edit] OP says "same problem its stuck"

*Without seeing server code* I am offering that the the answer is...

Server side is not sending any form of "End-of-File".  The server simple stops sending data.  The receive end does not "know" there is no more data, it simple "knows" no more data is available at that time an so patiently waits.

(in order of preference)

1) Insure the server does indeed `close()`, this *should* cause `read()` to eventually return < 0 (See @nos comments).

2) Have the server *only* send a special character when it is the last.  ASCII codes 26 (^Z) and 255 (truncated typical EOF) are typical candidates.  Then when the received receives such, it stops.

3) Form data packets.  Server prepends the data sent with a length.  Client end uses this length. A negative value could be used to indicate error or EOF.

Comment: @user2103930 What about the server side ? Did you verify that the server closes the connection like I asked you to check in the comments ? The server closing the connection is the only way your while loop will end.

Comment: thanx i ive tried to close server its worked,but if i want not to close server and client socket,what is the solution???